# How to make an editable table using ASP.NET Web Pages?

Tags: html-table, forms, asp.net-webpages

I'm fairly new to html development and don't know how to tackle this problem. I need to create a table with some editable cells. Then I need to update a specific row in a database table based in the row edited. I've created some working solution that I'm almost sure don't use a correct approach to the problem, so I need to know how can I can I make this fine.
Note the **repeated form**. I would like to have only one form and one submit button to update only those edited rows.

```
@using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
@using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;
@{

    string some_conn = "SomeConnectionString";
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(some_conn);
    var comm = new OracleCommand("select * from some_table",conn);
    conn.Open();


    if(IsPost){
        var some_id = Request.Form["some_id"];
        var some_value = Request["some_value"];

        var update_comm = new OracleCommand("update some_table"+
                                            "   set some_value ='"+some_value+"'" +
                                            " where some_id ='" + some_id + "'", conn ) ;
        update_comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    var dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <table>
            @while(dr.Read()){
                <tr>
                @for(int i= 0; i < 7 ; i++){
                    if(i != 5){
                        <td> @(Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(i)))</td>    
                    }
                }
                    <form method="post" action="">

                    <td> <input type="text" name="some_id" contenteditable="false" value="@(Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(5)))"></td>
                    <td><textarea name="some_value" cols="10" rows="10">@(Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(7)))</textarea></td>  
                    <td> <input type="submit" value="update"></td>
                    </form>
            </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
@{
    conn.Close();
    conn.Dispose();

}
```